# why I can not get one signal push notification message on my test device?

Tags: flutter, dart, onesignal

I added phone to one signal as a test device.But when I send a notification to my test device nothing occures.When I send for all users.I get notification.
[image: As you see it says not subscribed]

```
class OneSignalApi {
  static Future setUpOneSignal() async {
    final String? deviceId = await PlatformDeviceId.getDeviceId;
    final String deviceLang = ui.window.locale.languageCode;

    //Remove this method to stop OneSignal Debugging
    OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose);

    OneSignal.initialize(
      "aasghdgashdgjaskdu",
    );

    OneSignal.login(deviceId!);

// The promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse function will show the iOS or Android push notification prompt. We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission
    OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);
   
    OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((event) {
      if (event.notification.additionalData != null) {

        Get.to(() => NewsDetailScreen(
            news: News(
                id: '05eda4e4276ceddb4959cb368c287bdf',
                category: 'dunya',
                pubDate: 'aprel')));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You can have a look to this code.I call setUpOneSignal() method like that.in order to get test notifications should I add something into code block?

I read the documentation of onesignal ,but I do not think that I miss something.
Could you please help me?